# How do I make fancyhdr respect the margins?

Tags: header-footer, margins, fancyhdr

I am trying to make the following document with margins that the *fancy headers* even respect, not just the text inside the main page box:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage[left=2.0cm,right=2.0cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\lhead{violates margin}


\begin{document}

Only here the margins counts

\end{document}
```

Is it possible to have the "violates margin" appear with a 2.5 cm margin and then below it the main text?

Comment: the margins looks ok to me. Don't forget that the text line has a parindent, so check with more text.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, but the header "violates margin" -- is exactly what I want to respect the margins too (meaning, be 2.5cms below the top) -- though, judging by your answer, this is not the traditional way of thinking of margins. Is there still a way to do that?

Comment: sorry I have no idea what you mean. Make a picture (and add more text, e.g. with the lipsum package.)

Comment: Look at the `geometry` package documentation. The headers and footers are inside the top and bottom margins (Figure 1 and 2a), unless you use the `includehead` and `includefoot` options (Figure 2b). Is that what you want?

Comment: @PietervanOostrum yes, thank you.